# SELECT total votes for new & returning users in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables: votes and users. I would like to be show the count (not sum) of total votes for new registered users by date next to the total votes of that day.

Time frame for the query can be all, I can later add from - to time frame.

So if I have 10 votes per Date X, I would like to know how many where generated by new users and how many by returning users as well as how many new and returning voted (* also to include new who didn't vote).

**votes:**

```
id | vote | user_id | created_at
1  | 30   | 28      | 2012-06-10
1  | 12   | 15      | 2012-06-10
1  | 30   | 28      | 2012-06-10
...
```

**users:**

```
users_ id | created_at
28        | 2012-06-01
29        | 2012-06-03
30        | 2012-06-10
...
```

and the result i'm looking to get is this:

```
Date | total votes | votes for new | votes for returning | total new users | total returning users
```

thanks!

----- current code:

```
        SELECT
      DATE(created_at) AS Date,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Votes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Votes',
      SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'Users' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total Users'
    FROM
    (
        SELECT created_at, 'Votes' `Type` FROM votes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT created_at, 'Users'        FROM users
    ) t
    GROUP by DATE(created_at)
    ORDER by DATE(created_at) DESC
```

Comment: joes_nator, do you have any code that you have tried..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE just the select which I can do though not connect all the different ones efficiently

Comment: @DJKRAZE I must be missing something... there is nothing in mysql on the page you sent...

Comment: I sent this link to you by mistake, can you paste a copy of what your Select Statement looks like you have to utilize a Join statement as well

Comment: @DJKRAZE  here is my current code... (see above)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal new user is someone who registered on the same day and the date in the row - same for votes for new or returning can be done via user_id

Comment: @MahmoudGamal yep that's true

Comment: @SaharshShah It will even help me to start if you can show me how to get the total votes and total new users (i.e. registered on the same date as the vote) so the result will be something like this: Date | Total Votes by new users | total new users voting

Comment: @MahmoudGamal to answer your question: if a user registered yesterday and voted, then came today and voted again then he will be counted yesterday in the 'votes for new' and 'total new', for today he will be counted in 'votes for returning' and 'total returning users' - does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider breaking this up in several queries. If i understood you right, this should be what you are looking for.

All votes pr date:

```
SELECT created_at AS date, COUNT(*) AS totalvotes FROM votes GROUP BY created_at;
```

All votes by new users pr date

```
SELECT v.created_at AS date, COUNT(*) AS newuservotes FROM votes v INNER JOIN users u WHERE v.user_id = u.user_id AND v.created_at = u.created_at GROUP BY v.created_at;
```

All votes by old users pr date

```
The two numbers subtracted
```

If you want the entire thing in one query:

```
SELECT totvotes.date AS date, totvotes.totalvotes AS totalvotes, IFNULL(newvotes.newuservotes, 0) AS newuservotes, totvotes.totalvotes-IFNULL(newvotes.newuservotes, 0) AS olduservotes
FROM 
(
SELECT created_at AS date, COUNT(*) AS totalvotes FROM votes GROUP BY created_at
) totvotes
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT v.created_at AS date, COUNT(*) AS newuservotes FROM votes v INNER JOIN users u WHERE v.user_id = u.user_id AND v.created_at = u.created_at GROUP BY v.created_at
) newvotes ON totvotes.date = newvotes.date
```

Tested with 
mysql> select * from users;

```
+---------+------------+
| user_id | created_at |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2012-06-01 |
|       2 | 2012-06-02 |
|       3 | 2012-06-03 |
+---------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> select * from votes;

```
+----+------+---------+------------+
| id | vote | user_id | created_at |
+----+------+---------+------------+
|  1 |   10 |       1 | 2012-06-01 |
|  2 |   20 |       1 | 2012-06-10 |
|  3 |   30 |       2 | 2012-06-02 |
|  4 |   40 |       2 | 2012-06-10 |
+----+------+---------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| date       | totalvotes | newuservotes | olduservotes |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2012-06-01 |          1 |            1 |            0 |
| 2012-06-02 |          1 |            1 |            0 |
| 2012-06-10 |          2 |            0 |            2 |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Something similar could be used for "Never voted" users and so forth

I wasn't sure about how versed you are in SQL, so if there is any questions please comment and i will update the ansver.